# Generics which admit parameters; or parameterizable generics

Tags: java, generics, nested-generics

I've got an interesting architecture I'm playing with.  People can make Stores, which contain StoredObjects.  Stores can support different operations represented by interfaces (i.e. Get, Put, Print).

Here's what it looks like, highly simplified:

```
interface Put<Foo>{
   public void put(Foo f); 
}

class Store implements Put<Store.Obj<?>> {
    class Obj<T> {
        public T o;
    }
    @Override
    public void put(Obj<?> o) { }


}

public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args){
                Store s = new Store();
                Store.Obj<String> o = s.new Obj<>();
                s.put(o);

        }
}
```

The problem arises when I'd like to implement the similar "get" method.  Ideally, I'd like an interface which looks like this:

```
interface Get<Foo> {
    public <T> T get(Foo<T> f);
}
```

Obviously, this is malformed java.  Is there some syntax (or hack) that I can use to accomplish what this is meant to do?  Effectively, instead of specifying a constant type as a generic parameter, I want to specify a parameterizable type as a generic parameter (which will then itself be parameterized in the get method). Yes, this boils down to higher-kinded types, which java doesn't have; so crazy-ugly hacks more than welcome!

Common solutions which won't work due to other design constraints:

- moving the get/put/etc operations into the inner `Obj` class
- creating some supertype of `Store.Obj<T>` and specifying the interfaces to take that, rather than a generic parameter.

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand the question. What are you trying to accomplish? Maybe you want something like <T extends Foo> ?

Comment: Not really, no; Java's type system doesn't support higher-kinded types, which is the term for what you're looking for.

Comment: @LouisWasserman that's too bad.  I'm coming from a C++ land, which (super by accident) actually does have these sorts of higher-kinded types.

Answer (score 0):

You need some way to get the T out of your Obj. Let's call this a *Getter*.

```
interface Getter<O, I> {
    I get(O outer); // get the "inner" value out of the "outer" object
}
```

Now you could implement a getter for your `Obj` class:

```
class ObjTGetter<T> implements Getter<Obj<T>, T> {
    public T get(Obj<T> o) { return o.o; }
}
```

Now your `Store` constructor must also contain a `Getter` parameter, so you can use it to implement get. Your Store class then becomes:

```
class Store<O, I> implements Put<O>, Get<O, I> {
    private Getter<O, I> getter;
    public void put(O o) { … }
    public I get(O o) { … }
}
```

But by then you can also get rid of your `Store` and use the getter directly.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose we can forget about the higher-kinded types from the beginning and you know that what you suggest is not possible.

This is not solution you probably want, but this was my best short at the problem.

Since we cannot create new parametric types, then we will have to resort to creating new parametric values instead.

First, we have to state that `Foo` is a generic type. As matter of fact there is a type in Java 8 that is better: `Supplier<T>`

```
interface Supplier<T> {
  T get()
}
```

Now, let's say I had to values of this type:

```
Supplier<String> s = () -> "Hello";
Supplier<Integer> i = () -> 42;
```

Well, since we don't have higher kinded types, as already established, then our `Get` interface will have to be coupled with some generic types at compile time:

```
interface Get<S, F extends Supplier<S>> {
    public S get(Supplier<S> foo);
}
```

The problem is, evidently, that you would need multiple instances/values of `Get` for every possible type T of `Supplier<T>`, so we'd had an explosion of values:

```
Get<String, Supplier<String>> f = Supplier::get;
Get<Integer, Supplier<Integer>> g = Supplier::get;
```

And then we can do

```
String m = f.get(); //yield "Hello"
Integer n = g.get(); //yields 42
```

The supplier can pretty much contain whatever you want, but I don't think we can escape defining multiple Get instances.